# how do you test polymer components written in ES6/ES2015 with web-component-tester?

Tags: polymer, ecmascript-6, web-component-tester

starting with polymer-starter-kit 1.1.0 I modified all existing code in the kit to ES6/ES2015, including the following: `gulpfile.js, app.js, routing.html, my-greeting.html, my-list.html, my-greeting-basic.html and my-listing-basic.html`. After following the instructions of the es6 babel recipe, found in the docs folder, I ran `gulp serve` to verify application works correctly and it does, except all of the existing tests fail with the following message ...

```
chrome 48                ✖ Test Suite Initialization

  Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

chrome 48                Tests failed: 2 failed tests
```

the above is true for `chrome 41`, `firefox 44` and `safari 9.0` as well

it seems like wct runs the uncompiled code and i can't find any options that will allow the wct gulp tasks to compile first or for that matter point to either the `.tmp` or `dist` folders to test.

here is one of the modified examples ...

```
<!--
@license
Copyright (c) 2015 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
-->
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<dom-module id="my-list">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <ul>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
        <li><span class="paper-font-body1">{{item}}</span></li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script>
    (() => {
      'use strict';

      class MyList {

        beforeRegister() {
          let is = this.constructor.name
            .replace(/\W+/g, '-')
            .replace(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2')
            .toLowerCase();

          this.is = is;

          this.properties = {
            items : {
              type   : Array,
              notify : true,
            }
          };
        }

        ready() {
          this.items = [
            'Responsive Web App boilerplate',
            'Iron Elements and Paper Elements',
            'End-to-end Build Tooling (including Vulcanize)',
            'Unit testing with Web Component Tester',
            'Routing with Page.js',
            'Offline support with the Platinum Service Worker Elements'
          ];
        }
      }

      Polymer(MyList);
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the offical Polymer-Starter-Kit adds documentation to the [Add ES2015 support through Babel](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/add-es2015-support-babel.md) document, describing the prefered method of testing ES6/ES2015 code, my fork [Polymer-Starter-Kit](https://github.com/Nejat/polymer-starter-kit) has a modified `gulpfile.js` and `wtc.conf.js` that allows ES6/ES2015 Elements, Tests & Code to test correctly.

Basically I modified the `wtc.conf.js` configuration file to point to `dist` instead of `app` for test suites and the`bower_components` path mapping. To make sure the project is built properly the `wct` gulp tasks, in `gulpfile.js`, were injected with the same dependencies as the `gulp serve` task.

**DISCLAIMER** - *Let me say that I don't think is the ideal method, it's only a temporary patch solution so I can continue working with tests and ES2015.*

*I personally like how `WTC` currently doesn't require a build, making the development process more fluid and dynamic. Maybe, it can inject Babel browser support when it detects ES2015.*